# Hide header and footer while printing a webcontrol using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, printing, web-controls, printing-web-page

How can I hide the header like 'Page 1 of 1' and footer (url) when printing  a webcontol in ASP.NET?

I currently doing by opening a new page on Print button click ande in it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( null != Session["Control"] )
    {
        Control ctrl = ( Control )Session["Control"];
        PrintManager.PrintWebControl( ctrl );
        Session["Control"] = null;
    }
}
```

This will print the header and footer. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting is configured by the user in their browser. Their is no way to disable it from code. You'r best bet is to include instructions on how to configure/disable the settings.

See an example here:
http://www.xheo.com/products/sps/default.aspx?print=true

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS styles and specify they apply to a media type of print. See this article for help; http://www.cantoni.org/articles/printstyle

Basically create a seperate stylesheet for print styles only. If you want to hide something on the page use `{ display:none }` as one of that elements style attributes. Then link your stylesheet in the HEAD element;

```
<link href="print.css" media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: This definately helps when printing but still doesn't eliminate the settings that the user has chosen in their browser...at least not for IE.

Comment: Right, I slightly misunderstood the question, I see they mean the actual browsers print header and footer. I guess Firefox may have this ability somewhere but IE is too closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, and you can have the client install [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8966).

Otherwise, if you are using Internet Explorer: google for "*MeadCo ScriptX*"

(FF option is free, IE option is free for basic functionality only)

Answer (score 0):

For this we are using print class like it

```
public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl)
{
    PrintWebControl(ctrl, string.Empty);
}

public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl, string Script)
{
    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    if (ctrl is WebControl)
    {
        Unit w = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage); ((WebControl)ctrl).Width = w;
    }
    Page pg = new Page();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    if (Script != string.Empty)
    {
        pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pg.GetType(), "PrintJavaScript", Script);
    }
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();

    pg.Controls.Add(frm);
    // done changes on below 1 line for unassigned header URL //
    frm.ResolveUrl("");
    frm.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    frm.Controls.Add(ctrl);

    pg.DesignerInitialize();

    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();        
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

here just change a line in form property and set

```
frm.ResolveUrl("");
```

so URl is not visible when page is print..i use it successfuly.